# Connecting to multiple USB Bluetooth 4.0 dongles in a single app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm running into a hardware issue where connecting multiple bluetooth LE devices causes a bottleneck and I can not connect more than 5 or 6 without issues. I have external USB Bluetooth 4.0 (LE) dongles that I can connect to my Mac. I know that the IOS Simulator requires that you have an external USB Dongle to use Bluetooth in the simulator.

Is there a way to attach to additional dongles programmatically and reliably?

Comment: I don't know if I follow where you're having issues. Do you have one USB dongle and multiple BT LE devices you're trying to connect to with that, or multiple dongles on the same computer? Is this a Mac application you're trying to connect from or an iOS one?

Comment: I have one Bluetooth LE chip built into the MBP. I also have several [CSR Bluetooth LE Dongles](http://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=DEV-SYS-1487-1B&x=10&y=19&cur=USD) The OS will only allow you to have one active bluetooth HCI but you can connect to a second Bluetooth LE HCI needed for [iPhone Bluetooth LE development](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2295/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012211) There should be a way to attach an application to a non-active Bluetooth HCI.  Mac app I'm looking at creating.